# What if two planes areas are supposed to be a volume?

Tags: calculus

I was taught there is no area underneath a point in 2-dimensions; after that I didn't think about a problem such as the area of two combined rectangles' areas.

- Supposing that there are two points with no area under them they couldn't be added for any area, so by that rationale adding the areas of two rectangles would not give a volume.
- That makes my question: how much volume is there between two $``$subsequent$"$ or infinitesimally-close rectangles or "one rectangle touching the other?" Because the first point suggests there isn't even one...

Comment: Well in 3-d volume of a cuboid is length times width times height. If your region is two "infinitessimally close" parallel rectangles that would give zero volume since one factor is "infinitessimally close" to zero, so it *is* zero for any definition in terms of coordinates that could be given.

Comment: A line segment (between the $x$ axis and a point) has no area, but on the other hand non-zero Riemann sums exist. I wonder what this question is really about; how did the topic of two "infinitesimally-close rectangles" come up?